# Thumbs.db are automatically deleted

Tags: sharepoint-online, delete, thumbnail

We recently faced a strange behaviour that on various SharePoints hundreds of *thumbs.db*-files are deleted without any user interaction. These files appear in the recycle bin.
There are users listed as "deleted by" but they did not perform any action.

What causes this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are your users using the OneDrive sync client?  If so, Windows is probably creating the thumbs.db locally in the synced folders and the OneDrive Sync client is uploading them to SharePoint.  If the thumbs.db are deleted locally, the sync client will delete them in SharePoint as the user of the Sync Client.

Do you run Disk Cleanup on your systems to remove thumbnails?

If you are using the OneDrive Sync client be sure to update to the latest version. Microsoft updates it regularly and fixes many issues.

Comment: Yes, we use the Onedrive client but users don't delete these files by themselves nor do we ha e an automated cleaning process. It seems SharePoint does it by itself...